# Sanity desk error: Could not fetch list items Error: Could not establish EventSource connection

Tags: sanity

I've used the desk a few times and had no issues, but I was following along with the tutorial for [Live Preview](https://www.sanity.io/guides/nextjs-live-preview) and yesterday all my studios on my laptop began generating the above error while trying to load documents ([error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLeRR.png)).

Things I have tried:

1. Other browsers - Chrome was where error originated, also occurs in Firefox and Edge.
2. `sanity debug` in command line
3. Logging out and back into Sanity on the command line
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling nvm
5. Initializing a studio from another computer - the studio worked as normal from my desktop, so it seems that the problem is localized to my laptop and not an account issue.

Interestingly, I can switch to Vision in the studio and query the dataset successfully. The issue only arises when attempting to load documents for viewing/editing in Desk.